# LyX - multiline math environement left indentation

Tags: lyx, indentation

How to make all of my lines left indented?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! There are various ways, but it may depend on the real equations. What is the code that yields the second screenshot?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "left indented". E.g., do you mean left-aligned, left-hanging-indented, or something else. Please be specific.

Comment: @Mico left-aligned

Answer (score 1):

The term left-aligned in your formatting objective could be interpreted in several ways. Hopefully, one of the following two possibilities satisfies your objective.

[image]

The proper amount of kerning in the right-hand side solution will depend on the math font and the font size in use.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}  % for 'matrix*' environment
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{matrix*}[l]
  \left\{\begin{matrix*}[l] abc \\ def \end{matrix*}\right.\\
  ghi\\
  jkl
\end{matrix*}
\qquad\text{or}\qquad
\begin{matrix*}[l]
  \left\{\begin{matrix*}[l] abc \\ def \end{matrix*}\right.\\
  % Kerning amount found by trial and error:
  \mkern13.5mu ghi\\ 
  \mkern13.5mu jkl
\end{matrix*}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you but i am trying to do this in lyx.. not latex

Comment: @Shlomi - I'm afraid I don't understand your comment: `lyx` is a front-end to LaTeX. They're not mutually exclusive.